# removing duplicates in a string using set and get it back without order

Tags: python

Inspired by the suggestion [Recursive implementation of permutations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576231/recursive-implementation-of-permutations-in-python) to use a set to avoid duplicated for permutations in a string, I was thinking of using a set as a general method to remove duplicated from a string (obviously order won't be preserved).

So If I have

```
str1 = 'Thiss'
set_str1 = set(str1)
print set_str1
```

Output
set(['T','h', 'i', 's'])

The question is how to get the string back from this set. I was thinking that I can just use set and then convert it back to a string and then find permutations of the modified string. Is that an efficient way to go about it?  Also I don't want to use itertools because I am just preparing for some interviews.

Comment: I don't understand: do you want to preserve order or not? If you do `"".join(set_str1)` you will join the set into a string, but it might not be in the same order, so you're not getting "the string back" as you're asking.

Comment: If you are going to find permutations of the string, then you don't need to turn it back; just treat the set as the sequence from which to generate permutations.

Comment: So you would wan't `"Thsiss"` to become `"Thsi"`, correct?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841303/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-characters-from-a-string

Comment: No for permutations, I don't want to preserve order David. Martijn, the permutation output should be a list of strings. So I should just use join statement to create strings from elements of a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, sets don't preserve order, you may/may not get the original string back, but you can get a string of the elements using `join()`. Like follows -

```
>>> "".join(set(['T','h', 'i', 's']))
'ihsT'
```

Then, you can use `itertools.permutations` to find the permutations.

```
>>> list(permutations("".join(set("Thisss"))))
[('i', 'h', 's', 'T'), ('i', 'h', 'T', 's'), ('i', 's', 'h', 'T'), ('i', 's', 'T', 'h'),
  ... ]
```

Then, similarly apply `join` to get the elements in string format from the permutations list.

**You don't need to join the set to get the permutations though.**

Just doing

```
>>> list(permutations(set("Thisss")))
```

Gives similar answer, and then you can join the elements.

Comment: There is **no need** to turn the set into a string to generate permutations.

Comment: Yes. I was just giving an example of how he could get a string back, since he may need to join them in the end.

Comment: But then you use that string as input for the `permutations()`, which is entirely redundant and makes little sense.

Comment: I agree. I added a note in the end. Should I just remove the first statement all together?

Comment: Martijn wanted to implement permutations on my own for interviews :) without using the itertools.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to recreate the string; sets do not have a set ordering anyway, and a set suffices to create permutations:

```
>>> for p in permutations(set('Thiss')):
...     print(''.join(p))
... 
Tsih
Tshi
Tish
Tihs
Thsi
This
sTih
sThi
siTh
sihT
shTi
shiT
iTsh
iThs
isTh
ishT
ihTs
ihsT
hTsi
hTis
hsTi
hsiT
hiTs
hisT
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I wanted to do it without itertools but I think your answer still makes sense.

Comment: I suppose I should apply my permutation program on the set even if I don't use the itertools and finally convert to list of strings. Isn't it inconvenient to do it in sets given that we cannot reference sets using an index so I cannot use recursion on elements of the set. Perhaps I should convert the set to a list and write the permutation?

Comment: If your algorithm requires indexing, then by all means convert the set to a list, yes!

Comment: If I use an algorithm without indexing using sets, then I will perhaps need to remove one element from a set to create a subset which may not be that inefficient either.

Comment: FWIW, the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) turns the iterable into a tuple too.

Comment: Oh, ok so it is better to turn the set into a tuple instead of a list.